# How to display image from path in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

## DosyaYolu.cshtml

```
@{
  Layout = null; 
  string dosyaYolu = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Adsiz.jpg");
 }

<img src="@dosyaYolu" />
```

I could not display image from dosyaYolu path.What will I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Please just the pass the URL as itself. Because Server.MapPath will change the URL which can understandable by machine not by the browser.

It will be useful when the image file is inside of the your application.

Just pass the URL as

```
 @{
    Layout = null; 
    var dosyaYolu = @Url.Content("~/Views/Home/Adsiz.jpg");
  }

<img src="@dosyaYolu" />
```

Comment: Did you check path in your browser as match with your exact value

Comment: I checked.In my opinion, there is only one problem that picture is in Views directory.I tried to put picture in Content directory,then it worked correctly.